# Why won't Eclipse detect these files as part of my folder?

Tags: java, eclipse

I've got a bunch of class files for a Java project, but it's not detecting them as part of the folder.

Finder: https://i.stack.imgur.com/arbYw.png

Eclipse: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhWSi.png

It's annoying that I can't seem to access them.

Comment: Did you "refresh" the project view?

Comment: Yes, but see my reply to Zove.

Comment: Without knowing more it'll be difficult to help; you could edit your question to include a *textual* tree of the source directory|ies in question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right click the project, and click "Refresh". That should solve it. You can also go to the preferences and enable "Refresh by native hooks or polling" and "refresh on Access" in General > Workspace

Comment: Why does it do this after? It seemingly duplicates them outside of the package. http://i.imgur.com/O2JsA.png

Comment: That is the reason I hate it, many things it does not do for you. so SLOW, many many things

Comment: NetBeans is automatic, I think...but I have to use Eclipse for LibGDX >:[

Comment: It's automatic if you go to the General->Workspace preference page and tell it to do it automatically.

Comment: It DUPLICATES them? Huh? I think you should delete the project from eclipse (Make sure NOT to check "Delete from hard disk") and the make a new project with the same name. It should say "Eclipse will apply JRE settings based on the existing project" and should fix the problem. If it doesn't try getting a clean copy of eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

If you copy files into the project folder via the Finder (or Windows Explorer), then by default you need to refresh Eclipse in order to sync it to the underlying file system.  Alternatively, you can avoid copying files into the project outside of Eclipse and instead use Eclipse's Navigator (similar to Finder) or Package Explorer views -- you can drag from the file system and drop into the Navigator view, for example.

There are also a couple of Refresh options in Eclipse > Preferences > General > Workspace which may help to automatically sync things.

Answer (score 0):

Never ever try doing something on the file system if you want to change something inside Eclipse. Eclipse has its own view on the world, which is the so called workspace. And only that workspace matters.

Therefore please just create a new Java project in Eclipse and afterwards use File -> Import -> General -> File System to import the existing Java files into a source folder of your Java project.